# Is there a way to manipulate lines in logcheck rules before sending?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logs

There are a few cases, such as netfilter logs, where it would be great if I could send the report `logcheck` is about to send through a filter.

`logcheck(8)` doesn't seem to describe anything like this, nor does the `man` page for `logcheck.conf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly with `logcheck`. The only thing you have at your disposal is to filter lines from log files. There's a decent collection of filter examples here i this article titled: [logcheck — various filters](https://www.nooblet.org/blog/2013/logcheck-various-filters/).

However, given `logcheck` is merely a shell script you could modify it and create your own version. You could also modify the cronjob that typically comes with the `logcheck` package and run it via STDOUT, filtering the contents, and then sending that out via email yourself manually.

```
( $ /usr/sbin/logcheck -o | ...your filter... ) | mail ...
```

#### Custom filters

For setting up filters you can stick rule files under `logcheck`'s directory tree in the appropriate directory to get it to filter out messages that aren't relevant.

```
$ ls -ld /etc/logcheck/*
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 May 30 16:36 /etc/logcheck/cracking.d
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 May 30 16:36 /etc/logcheck/ignore.d.paranoid
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 May 30 16:36 /etc/logcheck/ignore.d.server
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 May 30 16:36 /etc/logcheck/ignore.d.workstation
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2647 Feb 16  2013 /etc/logcheck/logcheck.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  133 Feb 16  2013 /etc/logcheck/logcheck.logfiles
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 May 30 16:36 /etc/logcheck/violations.d
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 May 30 16:36 /etc/logcheck/violations.ignore.d
```

For example it comes with filter files for many of the popular services already:

```
$ ls /etc/logcheck/ignore.d.server/ | head -10
acpid
amandad
amavisd-new
anacron
anon-proxy
apache
apcupsd
arpwatch
asterisk
automount
```

So you could incorporate rules to filter things out there.

```
$ more /etc/logcheck/ignore.d.server/apache 
^\w{3} [ :0-9]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ apache: nss_ldap: reconnect(ing|ed) to LDAP server(\.\.\.| after [0-9]+ attempt\(s\))$
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Sorry if my question was unclear. I know how to filter them *out*. What I don't know is how to manipulate them in a way that makes (some of) them more readable in my MUA. Modifying the cron job is not the perfect solution, but perhaps I can "divert" the execution (given I am on Ubuntu).